# How to give value to the bootstrap switch button?

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in codeigniter where I've an option to show the data in the front page or not.

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
<label>Show in Front</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="switch-change" name="show-infront" checked data-on-text="YES" data-off-text="NO" checked data-on-color="success" data-off-color="warning">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[name='show-infront']").bootstrapSwitch();
</script>
```

When I print the value of the form in controller like `echo $this->input->post('show-infront')`, when 'yes' is checked, the output is 'on' and when 'no' is checked, there is no any output. So, I want that when I check yes, then the value should be 'yes' and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

try: onSwitchChange ...
OK so if checkbox in not checked not send its value in POST, so you need a hidden field like this:
also need set its value at init and onChange

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch-change" name="show-infront" data-on-text="YES" data-off-text="NO" checked data-on-color="success" data-off-color="warning">
<input type="hidden" name="show-infront-val"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ckbox = $("[name='show-infront']");
    var ckbox_val = $("[name='show-infront-val']");

    ckbox.on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch init.bootstrapSwitch', function(event,  state) {
        if (this.checked) ckbox_val.val('Yes')
        else ckbox_val.val('No')
    });

   ckbox.bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
</script>
```

Btw if you check php-s isset($_POST['show-infront']) also a good option for one checkbox

[Documentation](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/documentation-3.html)

Comment: It's not working on mine. It's showing 'on' and 'blank' for respective 'yes' and 'no'. Can you suggest me another solution?